# embedded credentials PHPUnit chromedriver

Tags: php, selenium, testing, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

Is their any possibility to run a PHPUnit Selenium test with embedded credentials? Since chromedriver 59 their is no way to start a test with embedded credentials in the url, like that:
`https://user:password@test.testweb.de`

> My solution:
>   1. Include the auth basic + Link to a file they are already exists on the server
>   2. Jump back to the URL without auth basic

```
'init_url'=>'https://user:password@test.testweb.de/robots.txt'
'base_url'=>'https://test.testweb.de'

$this->webDriver->get($config['platform']['testweb']['init_url']);
$this->webDriver->get($config['platform']['testweb']['base_url']);
```

Comment: Good question., Why don't you add the `userinfo` to the base-URL as well?

Comment: Because Google blocked this feature since chromedriver 59 https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856

Comment: But isn't that only for sub-resources? Which means the actual page should still work with credentials, but just not for images etc? But maybe I'm just misinterpreting that.

Comment: No you're right. But I need the sub-resources, like images, css etc, to run my tests. Thats the only reason.